# django returned form option selected

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I have a drop down menu from which people can select an area and submit.
On being directed to the results page I would like the chosen area to be displayed in the form. Convention is that you use selected as an attibute in the option tag.

Using django,

area = area queryset to populate the drop down list.
q = chosen for area.
Both can be renderd fine in the template seperately.
However when I try,

```
<form action="/results/" method="GET">
    <select name="q" id="id_area">
        {% if a %}
            {% for area in a %}
                <option value="{{ area }}" {% if area == q %} selected {% endif %}>{{ area }}</option>      
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </select>
    <p><input class="send_button" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
```

It doesn't give the "selected" attibute.

Also tried,

```
{% for area in a %}
    <option value="{{ area }}" {% ifequal area q %} selected {% endif %}>{{ area }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using Django forms for this?

Comment: Well because I thought it would be easier/quicker and seeing as it's a very simple get request.... Would django forms solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the django template equality operator doesn't support `var == var` checking. I'd suggest adding a 'selected' property to area so you can say something like `{% if area.selected %}`.

Comment: Yes it does, since version 1.2.

Comment: The poster didn't specify a version, it might still be the problem.